# Purging workflow after couple minutes

Tags: workflow, aem

I have a Workflow step which if meet issues throw `WorkflowException` with a message and stacktrace, in effect - blocks whole workflow launcher with the payload. Finally, the workflow is indefinitely in the `RUNNING` state and does not handle any updates for blocked payload. This situation requires admin action to manually terminate the workflow.

There is how the simple workflow looks:

```
@Service
@Component
@Properties({
        @Property(name = Constants.SERVICE_DESCRIPTION, value = "Workflow"),
        @Property(name = "process.label", value = "Workflow Step") })
public class WorkflowStep implements WorkflowProcess {

    @Override
    public void execute(WorkItem workItem, WorkflowSession workflowSession, MetaDataMap metaDataMap)throws WorkflowException {       
        try {
            ... doing some stuff ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new WorkflowException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to check after i.e 2 minutes if the workflow is `COMPLETED` if not - terminate them to unblock the payload and after upload the next asset into this path - again handle by the workflow.

Any idea how to solve it without using `CRON Scheduler`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you catch the exception, why don't you terminate the workflow right then instead of throwing a WorkflowException?
You could log whatever you want, handle the error and then terminate...

BR,
Oliver